# One report as attachment and another as email body in ssrs 2008

Tags: email, reporting-services, subscriptions, formats

I have one summary report and one detailed report, i need to send mail to my client daily attaching detailed report (excel file) as attachment of mail and the summary report as body for the same mail.

How do I do this? How do I include two reports to one email? Can this be done in SSRS 2008?

Answer (score 0):

That functionality is not supported out-of-the-box. You might be able to write a custom extension to do it, but it's not going to be trivial.